# What does it mean when Duplicity exits with exit status 23?

Tags: backup, duplicity, exit-status

I'm running Duplicity for backup of my desktop to a remote storage. Everything has been working fine, but now I see in my log that Duplicity has been exiting with exit status 23 for a couple of runs. As of what I can see the backups are running and the backups are uploaded to the remote computer.

The exit status 23 seems to only happen when it's run in the background as a cron-job. When I run the backup script manually I get a 0 exit status.

Duplicity's man page lacks info on the meanings of the programs exit statuses, so I don't really know where to start.

`cat syslog.1` outputs:

...

```
Jan 23 12:54:35 xx anacron[998]: Job `cron.daily' started
Jan 23 12:54:35 xx anacron[4241]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2019-01-23
Jan 23 12:54:45 xx kernel: [  322.467223] EXT4-fs (sdb1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
Jan 23 12:54:45 xx kernel: [  322.473997] EXT4-fs (sdb1): recovery complete
Jan 23 12:54:45 xx kernel: [  322.474404] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jan 23 12:55:03 xx kernel: [  340.754000] EXT4-fs (sdc): recovery complete
Jan 23 12:55:03 xx kernel: [  340.794089] EXT4-fs (sdc): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

...

Comment: What's the error output from `cron`? (It's probably being emailed to your *local* user account.)

Comment: @Christopher, Interesting, could you cite the source for that?

Comment: @roaima Good point! Will look into that!

Comment: I now have the exact same issue, after having the cron script run for 3 years. So thanks for closing the question guys, I doubt I would have rephrased it much differently than the OP. Oh, and this is the nr. 1 result on Google for "Duplicity error 23". This could have been helpful.

Comment: @zmippie this question appears to have been abandoned. Within a day of it being posted I asked for additional information, but none came. I'd suggest you post a new question with at least the amount of detail here (including error output from `cron` please), and flag this dead question here as a duplicate of your new one. (Flag with a moderator if you can't actually mark it as a dup.)

Comment: @roaima Sorry, I think I've jumped the gun here, assuming the question was closed because the *initial* question did not contain enough details. But I now understand that it was closed because the OP didn't provide more details in response to your comment. Thanks for the headsup. The error 23 only occured once, so there's not much for me to add. There's very little information about this error though, so this question comes up quickly after a search.

Comment: @zmippie if you've a similar use case and want either to update this question or post your own that would be good (for everyone, and hopefully in particular for you).